# Division inequality constraint using google or-tools in Java

Tags: java, optimization, or-tools

I'm trying to solve a simple optimization problem using [Google OR-Tools GLOP solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop#java):

```
Goal = MAXIMIZE (X+Y)
Constraint: X/(X+Y) >= 10
```

I can't find an example for a division.
How can I do that in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constraint as written is not linear.
But you can rewrite it as:

```
maximize (x + y)

such that: 
    x >= 10 * (x + y)
```

Comment: I can see how that works for a constraint, but what if the Goal has a division? 
eg Goal=Maximize X/(X+Y)

Comment: As said this is a linear solver. Not a global continuous solver.

Comment: apologies, I didn't realise this was GLOP